# Image float left goes out of div

Tags: html, css

I have combined text with image however the cat goes out of the parent div. Is there any way to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/qn5LM/

```
<div style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC">
    <img style="float: left;" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" height="100px" width="100px" border="1px"/>
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this after the text `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CdVaR/)

Comment: so vote it up , i think you vote me down by mistake :)

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to vote up/down...

Answer (score 5):

A way of doing it without adding empty elements:

Add this css

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

And add the class clearfix to your div

```
<div style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC" class="clearfix">
    <img style="float: left;" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" height="100px" width="100px" border="1px"/>
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qn5LM/11/

Comment: Don't add an extra element. There are many nicer ways to get the same effect.

Comment: then misposition with my other divs

Comment: @Ms.Nobody — Because it is a duplicate question and I voted to have this one closed and marked as such instead.

Comment: Much nicer answer and solution.

Answer (score 2):

Add `float:left` to parent div as well

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qn5LM/2/)**

**OR**

Add `overflow:auto` to parent div

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is to add `overflow: hidden` to the style of the outer-div. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn5LM/5/)

```
<div style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC; overflow: hidden">
    <img style="float: left;" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" height="100px" width="100px" border="1px"/>
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When floating elements you are taking them out of the oringinal flow of the document.

Applying overflow:hidden; to the parent element is a quick way around this.

Please take a look at clearfix for more information:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Please note that:

> overflow: hidden; also hides the overflow, which may be undesirable behavior in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add **position: absolute** to the div...

```
<div style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC; position:absolute;">
    <img style="float: left" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" height="100px" width="100px" border="1px"/>
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
</div>
```